# Как определить на своем сервере user agent пользователя?

Tags: веб-сервер, useragent

Всем привет! Захожу на свой сервер с браузера и в запросе приходит информация о user agent навроде такой:

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36"

Как из этой инфы определить реальный браузер, я не могу понять. Конечно, я знаю, с какого браузера захожу сам, но что если это будет пользователь из сети? Какие существуют способы определения реального браузера (и других агентов), без обращения к сторонним онлайн сервисам при каждом запросе? Нужно для сбора статистики и защиты от угона сессий.

Comment: Этот user-agent можно подменить в два счета, строить на нем защиту не стоит

Comment: Строить защиту только на user-agent не буду. Но все же, для статистики подойдет, обычно мало кто подменяет. Ну и вопрос еще в том, какие способы есть определить агента, помимо чтения user-agent-заголовка?

Comment: Надежных нет никаких, все данные, поступающие с клиента, легко подменяются.

Comment: Как же тогда защищают сессии?

Comment: Не дают им утечь, например?